# How to store the values in DateTime object from ComboBox c#

Tags: c#

My question is: I have three ComboBox. One for days, months and years.
How to store the values that I selected in DateTime object when I press the button?

[image]
Note: I don't want to store in the database, it just in the object.

and I try this but it definitely doesn't work

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
     comboBox1.Items.Add("Jan");
     comboBox1.Items.Add("Feb");
     comboBox1.Items.Add("Mar");
}
```

--

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime DT = new DateTime();

            DT = comboBox1.Text;
}
```

Comment: Add some code and that will help better to understand what you are asking. What have you tried? and what are you expecting as a result?

Comment: Are you trying to have a user input day,month,year separately? and then display that result as a DateTime?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I edited my question as you said @janzen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in button

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           
                string L = comboBox1.GetItemText(comboBox1.SelectedItem);
              
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the built-in [DateTimePicker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker?view=netcore-3.1) control?  That's what it's for!

But to answer your question, put your values together into a String, then use [DateTime.TryParseExact()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=netcore-3.1#System_DateTime_TryParseExact_System_String_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_System_Globalization_DateTimeStyles_System_DateTime__) like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime dt;
    if (comboBoxMonth.SelectedItem != null &&
        comboBoxDay.SelectedItem != null &&
        comboBoxYear.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        string strDT = comboBoxMonth.SelectedItem.ToString() + " "
        + comboBoxDay.SelectedItem.ToString() + ", "
        + comboBoxYear.SelectedItem.ToString();
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(strDT, "MMM d, yyyy", culture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Date Parsed: " + dt.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Date: " + strDT);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Select a Date First!");
    }            
}
```